# Texture Resultion Problems

Tags: java, 3d, texture-mapping, texture2d, render-to-texture

I am trying to write a mini graphics engine for university project ,
so I added a texture to the engine with plane it works pretty good [Plane Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDryB.jpg)

but with sphere it work really bad even if the radius of sphere is really big ( 9000) .
[Sphere Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BB7Ne.jpg)

I used this formula :
(In class point) :

```
  public class LongLat{
        public double lat; 
        public double lon; 
        LongLat(double x1, double x2){
            lat = x1 ;
            lon = x2 ; 
        }

    }

     final   double E = 0.0000000848191908426;
     final  double D2R = Math.PI / 180;
     final double PiDiv4 = Math.PI / 4;
   final double HalfPi = Math.PI / 2;
   private final double C1 = 0.00335655146887969;
   private final double C2 = 0.00000657187271079536;
   private final double C3 = 0.00000001764564338702;
   private final double C4 = 0.00000000005328478445;
    public  LongLat ToLonLat( double Radius)
    {
        double x =this.xyz.d1 ; 
         double y = this.xyz.d3 ;
        double g = HalfPi - 2 * Math.atan(1 / Math.exp(y / Radius));
        double latRadians = g + C1 * Math.sin(2 * g) + C2 * Math.sin(4 * g) + C3 * Math.sin(6 * g) + C4 * Math.sin(8 * g);

        double lonRadians = x / Radius;

        double lon = lonRadians / D2R ;
        double lat = latRadians / D2R ;

        return new LongLat((float)lon, (float)lat);
    }
```

(In TSphere- Texture Sphere class ):

```
    Point.LongLat lt =pt.point.ToLonLat(sp.radius );
     double longitude = lt.lon ; 
     double latitude = lt.lat; 
    double PI = Math.PI; 
    // get x value
    int x = (int)(longitude+180)*(nX/360); 

    // convert from degrees to radians
    double latRad = latitude*PI/180;

    // get y value
    double  mercN = Math.log(Math.tan((PI/4)+(latRad/2)));
    int y = (int)( (nY/2)-(nX*mercN/(2*PI)));
    int color = image.getRGB(x % nX ,  y% nY ); 
    Color xc = new Color(new java.awt.Color(color));
    return xc ;
```

and it looks really pixelated for some reason , someone have an  idea how to fix that ?
Thanks Idan.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Texture.ImageCords TextureEmession(Point pt,int nX,int nY){ 
         //(−cossin,+sinsin 
         double O = Math.acos((new Vector(1,0,0)).dotProduct(this.getNormal(pt))) , 
           Q = Math.acos((new Vector(0,1,0)).dotProduct(this.getNormal(pt))) , sinq = Math.sin(Q) ; 
         return new Texture.ImageCords(( pt.getY() - pt.getX() *Math.cos(O)*sinq ), 
         (pt.getZ()  + pt.getX() *Math.sin(O) * sinq) ); 
     }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).